# Why can't I turn on an LED through Python?

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, led

I have an LED connected to pin 11 on the Raspberry Pi header, (also known as BCM/GPIO pin 17, and GPIO0). I have installed the Raspberry Pi Python library according to these instructions.

**Attempt 1**

I installed `RPi.GPIO` and used [the following code from eLinux](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Python). I see an error that 'setmode' is not an attribute of the GPIO library.

```
sudo python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 13 2013, 11:20:46)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>>> GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setmode'
```

**Attempt 2**

I used a different tutorial, yet I receive the following error:

```
    sudo python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 13 2013, 11:20:46)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>>> GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPi.GPIO-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 61, in setup
    id = _GetValidId(pin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPi.GPIO-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 52, in _GetValidId
    raise InvalidPinException
RPi.GPIO.InvalidPinException
```

I ***am*** able to turn on the LED using [the GPIO utility](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/):

```
gpio write 0 0
```

I have an earlier revision Raspberry Pi.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2708
Revision    : 0003
Serial      : 00000000396bd5ea
```

Why have I been unsuccessful in turning on an LED from Python?

---

Additional Resources

- *[RPi.GPIO module basics](http://code.google.com/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Discovered the problem:

Some guides online instruct you do download version 0.1.0 of the GPIO library which does not have the setup function. You must use a more recent version of the library.

```
RPi.GPIO-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

I have downloaded version 0.5.x and it works correctly.

```
RPi.GPIO-0.5.3a.tar.gz
```

Download from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO

or 
Download from here http://code.google.com/p/raspberry-gpio-python/downloads/list

---

**Installation Instructions**

Extract the script

```
tar -zxvf RPi.GPIO-0.5.3a.tar.gz
cd RPi.GPIO-0.5.3a
sudo python setup.py install
```

Here is a python example program that turns two leds off and on every second. It uses the actual pin names, not the GPIO pin names

```
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep

#Use the physical pin numbers, not the logical names
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#Set pin 11 and 12 as outputs
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

#Keep looping over and over
while True:

        #Turn pin 11 off and 12 on
        GPIO.output(11, False)
        GPIO.output(12, True)

        #Wait for 1 second
        sleep(1)

        #Turn pin 12 off and 11 on
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        GPIO.output(12, False)

        #Wait for 1 second
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: Could you post a new snippit of code to help others wit the same problem?  It would earn an upvote from me.

Comment: @Butters I've added some more details on what I did to get it working.